# Intersection of Kernels of infinitely many functionals

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f,f_n\in X^*$ be such that $\bigcap  \text{Ker}~ f_n\subset \text{Ker} ~f$. Then show that there exists $\alpha_i\in \mathbb{C}$ be such that 
$$f=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i f_i.$$

First of all, could not think of the least possibility of "existence" of $\alpha_i$..

I try to do the case of finite intersection. Let $1\leq i\leq n$. We have

$$f_i:\frac{X}{\text{Ker}(f_i)}\xrightarrow{\cong}\mathbb{C}$$

Consider map $$\eta:\frac{X}{\text{Ker}(f_1)}\times \frac{X}{\text{Ker}(f_2)}\times\cdots\times \frac{X}{\text{Ker}(f_n)}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
with $$\eta\left(\left(x_1+\frac{X}{\text{Ker}(f_1)},x_2+\frac{X}{\text{Ker}(f_2)},\cdots,x_n+\frac{X}{\text{Ker}(f_n)}\right)\right)=f_1(x_1)+f_2(x_2)+\cdots+f_n(x_n)$$

As this is a linear map from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$, this has to be given by  a row matrix and i thought this would give me $\alpha_i$. But could not proceed.

Give some hints.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The argument is more straight-forward than that. The map $F=(f_1,...,f_n)$ takes $X$ into ${\Bbb C}^n$ and the hypothesis is that $\ker F\subset \ker f$. A diagram chasing shows that there is a bounded linear map $h:{\Bbb C}^n \mapsto {\Bbb C}$ so that $f=h\circ F$ (it is unique if $F$ is surjective). And $h(y_1,...,y_n)=a_1y_1+\cdots a_ny_n$ gives you the wanted description of $f$. Again, it need not be unique unless the $f_i$'s are independent.

The result does not hold with infinitely many functionals without further (much stronger) conditions. A counter-example:

Let $X=\ell^2({\Bbb N}_0)$ and consider for $x=(x_0,x_1,...)$ the linear functionals: $f(x)=x_0$, and for $k\geq 1$: $f_k(x)=x_0-x_k$. Then:
$$ x\in \cap_k \ker f_k \Leftrightarrow x_0=x_1=x_2=... \Leftrightarrow x=0$$
The kernel is thus trivial and included in $\ker f$, but $f$ may not be written as a convergent linear combination of the $f_k$'s.

Comment: The problem is with the case of infinitely many functionals. There are no extra conditions given..